# Strange PHP autoload issue

Tags: php, class, function, datetime, autoload

I have some method which looks like that

```
public function getTime() {
    $date = new DateTime();
    $date->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('Europe/Paris'));
    return $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
}
```

Calling this method from inside file which has autoload function

```
function __autoload($class_name) {
    global $path;
    if (file_exists($path['classes'] . ds  . 'class.'. $class_name . '.php')) {
        require_once($path['classes'] . ds . 'class.'. $class_name . '.php');
    } else {
        die($path['classes'] . ds . 'class.'.$class_name . '.php');
    }
}
```

As you know, DateTime is in-built class of PHP. The problem is, script tries to load it from classes folder. This method works in my local server but remote webserver dies with following return.

`<path to classes folder>/class.DateTime.php`

What can I do in this case?

Comment: Does your remote server have PHP 5.2?

Comment: It's also recommended to use [`spl_autoload_register`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-register.php) in place of the magic `__autoload` method.

Comment: That `global $path` makes me sad.

Comment: try to print more debug information. for example which files are in the folder. are you sure class `<path to classes folder>/class.DateTime.php` does exist on the remote server?

Comment: @fuzzyDunlop changed __autoload() to spl_autoload_register . Whole script stopped working

Comment: @netcoder upgraded to VPS and this problem occured. Dunno version of PHP. Is there backward compatible way to do it?

Comment: I think @netcoder is on the right track.  What is the php version number of your server?  I'm guessing it is quite old and does not actually have the DateTime class built in.

Comment: @Cerad upgraded to VPS and this problem occured.really dunno version of PHP. Is there backward compatible way to do it?

Comment: @epic_syntax: Rewrite DateTime yourself, or upgrade PHP...

Comment: @epic_syntax you can find your php version by echoing `PHP_VERSION` in your script. `spl_autoload_register` is used differently to `__autoload()`, as described in the documentation.

Comment: or by writing on the shell `php -v`

Answer (score 7):

It may be the case that your method `getTime()` is trying to resolve a `DateTime` class in your current `namespace`.

If you wish to use the in-built `DateTime` class you will have to [refer to the global namespace](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.fallback.php).

**From this:**

```
public function getTime() {
    $date = new DateTime();
    $date->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('Europe/Paris'));
    return $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
}
```

**To this:**

```
public function getTime() {
    $date = new \DateTime();
    $date->setTimezone(new \DateTimeZone('Europe/Paris'));
    return $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
}
```