# how to prevent spl_autoload_register from loading native PHP classes

Tags: php, oop

I saw answers to similar questions but none of them worked for me
this is my implementation of the function:

```
 spl_autoload_register(function($class){
        require_once 'classes/'. $class .'.php';
});
```

so when i say

```
 $user = new User();
```

it works fine as i have a User.php file inside the classes folder with the class defenition
but when I use a native PHP class like

```
 $date = new Date();
```

I get the following error:

Fatal error: require_once() [function.require]: Failed opening required 'classes/Date.php'

I tried surrouding the require_once in a try block but it did work, i still get the same error

Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe this thread can help you? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9539422/strange-php-autoload-issue

Comment: thanks, adding a leading backslash to every class name? this doesn't seem right does it? I haven't seen it in professionals code before, is it the only way? I mean there must be something done by PHP guys for this issue that I am missing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `file_exists` to check if you have a class in your classes directory named with `$class`. If not, you don't require it.

If it is a PHP native class, it will work, otherwise it will throw you an error.

```
spl_autoload_register(function($class){
    if (file_exists('classes/'. $class .'.php'))
        require_once 'classes/'. $class .'.php';
});
```